# Filling in the blanks in a Kindle book

Tags: ebook-reader, ebooks, kindle-for-android

I'm considering buying a Kindle version of a workbook which requires a lot of blanks to be filled. I'm aware of "Note" feature in Kindle app for Android but texts that are entered this way do not show on book pages (in blanks) as they would in a paper version of the workbook  (there are only icons indicating notes) and this limits their usefulness.

Any ideas how to work around this and make Kindle workbooks as usable as the paperback ones?